# Instafeed / html responsive Section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an Instagram section on my website which works the way I want it but I want to add another div with background color and text to the right of it so it looks like it is part of the grid but it's not!

I have it set up but when scaling the browser it does not stay with it at all can anybody help me out? Here are my HTML and CSS and also an image on how it should look.

```css
.Container-Instagram {
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 85%;
}
.H1-Instagram {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #d7aa44;
}
.Instagram-Title {
  background-color: #f8db74;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 204px;
  margin-left: 792px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 187px;
  text-align: center;
}
.cross-text2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.cross-text2::before {
  background-color: #d7aa44;
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.Container-Instagram a {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 20%;
}
.Container-Instagram #instafeed a:first-child {
  margin-left: 40%;
}
.Container-Instagram #instafeed a:nth-child(8n + 8) {
  margin-left: 0.05%;
}

.instagram-section {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container-Instagram">
            <div class="Instagram-Title"><h1 class="H1-Instagram">Get On The <span class="cross-text2">Insta</span> Gram</h1></div>
            <div id="instafeed" class="instagram-section"></div>
        </div>
```

The snippet does not work because of the JS but it is just for showing my code. this is what the end result should look like(red squares are instagram posts):
[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnTDW.png)

Here is the web address I'm using to develop on if you want a better view of what I mean http://s749376357.websitehome.co.uk/ :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `margin-left:792px;` on `.Instagram-Title` replace it with `right:100px;` then add `position:relative;` to `.Container-Instagram` this will then follow as you resize - you will however still need to do some work to make it fully responsive.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, it seems to be doing the exact same thing